# Objective-C: Property not found on object of type

Tags: objective-c

So I am very new to Objective-C and I was trying to expand on a working program I made from a lesson book.

So, I have a working class names "Item". Here is Item.h:

```
@interface Item : NSObject

{
    NSString *_itemName;
    NSString *_serialNumber;
    int _valueInDollars;
    NSDate *_dateCreated;
}

+(instancetype)randomItem;
```

It has a few functions to manipulate those variables, initialize them in a costume way and print them in a formatted manner.

Then I made a sub-class of "Item" called "Container". I wanted it to be similar to "Item" but have a NSMUtableArray variable that could hold an Array of "Item"s. Here is Container.h:

```
#import "Item.h"

@interface Container : Item

{
    NSString *_containerName;
    NSDate *_containerDatecreated;
    int _containerValueinDollars;
    NSMutableArray *_subItems;
}

+(instancetype) randomContainer;
```

Now in my main. I do a number of things with the "Item" class and they work fine. But when I do this:

```
Container *container=[Container randomContainer];
        for (NSString *item in container.containerName) {
            NSLog(@"%@", item);
        }
```

It says "Property 'containerName' not found on object of type 'Container *'". But I clearly added that variable to the "Container" subclass.

Note: randomContainer creates a random container instance and does some initializing to it. When I debug in Xcode it seems to be working fine.

What is my problem?

Comment: "property" != "instance variable". also, this has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: Use properties, not just instance variables (ivars). If the lesson book does not use @properites than toss it and get something current.

Comment: A perfectly reasonable question; not sure why the down vote.   tl;dr  the problem is that you are learning from an outdated book and the compiler is giving you a confusing error message as a result of processing the ancient patterns.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will look for something up-to-date. You guys were a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`container.containerName` is called dot syntax.  It is the equivalent of `[container containerName]`.    But you don't have a property or method on your class named `containerName` so the compiler is complaining.

Now, that is likely entirely baffling in the context of the book you are using.  And that is because the book you are using is way way way out of date.

If it were up to date, your Item class would look more like:

```
@interface Item:NSObject
@property(copy) NSString *containerName;
@property(copy) NSDate *containerDateCreated;
@property(assign) NSInteger containerValueInDollars;
... etc ...
@end
```

Get yourself an up to date set of tutorials and/or books before learning anything else.   It'll save a lot of frustration.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I will look into something up to date. Thanks guys!